# MS Access Run-time Error 3162

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to use this code to copy a file to a new folder and add the file path/name to the DocName column in tblFileAttachments.

When I select the file to add, I keep getting this error "Run-time error 3162...You tried to assign the Null Value to a variable that is not a Variant data type."

Here are the tables I have

```
tblFileAttachments
 - DocID
 - DocName
 - RequestID_FK

tblRequests
 - RequestID
 - PFName
 - PLName
 - PBusinessName
```

I have a form based on tblFileAttachments with DocID, DocName and RequestID_FK fields. I also have a "Add File" button with the following code:

```
Private Sub btnAttachFile_Click()
Dim rsFile As DAO.Recordset
Dim strFilePath As String, strFilename As String
strFilePath = fSelectFile()
If strFilePath & "" <> "" Then
strFilename = Mid(strFilePath, InStrRev(strFilePath, "\") + 1)
With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblFileAttachments")
    .AddNew
    !DocID = Me.DocID
    !FilePath = strFilePath
    !FileName = strFilename
    .Update
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Debugging the error, it highlights

```
!DocID = Me.DocID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocID` is probably an Autonumber column?

Then don't assign it at all while creating the new record, simply leave out this line:

```
!DocID = Me.DocID
```

The ID will be generated automatically.